# C# DateTime Convert from String

Tags: c#

I am reading excel file in my C# .net web application and storing that value in Database. Ony of field in Excel is DateTime. I am storing it in string

```
string tran_time = Convert.ToString(odr[5]); //tran_time is "03-11-2012 16:08:43"
```

and then convert it in in DateTime and store it in Database (SQL Server 2008)

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(tran_time, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture);
```

But the Value Being stored in Database is in format

```
2012-05-11 13:40:23.000 (yyyy-mm-dd)
```

and the value in Excel is `05-11-2012 13:40:23 (dd-mm-yyyy)`

Date & Month is get replaced.

**My Question is How can i store it in Database in Format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:FFF)**

Comment: "But the Value Being stored in Database is in format [...]" - why aren't you storing it as a DateTime in the database? Then you don't *have* a format.

Comment: In Database that Column is of type "DateTime"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use yyyy-MM-dd format. Works like a charm:

```
string myString = dateVal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

> But the Value Being stored in Database is in format

No it isn't (assuming that you are using a `DATETIME` column type). This is just what the SQL tools **show** you.

A `DateTime` instance, either in a database or in C# **does not have an associated format**. It only gets formatted when **displayed** to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dd-mm-yyyy` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Comment: Then your input string does not contain the months in numeric format? Check out the MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx